# window.open() not working under subscribe scope in angular 2+

Tags: angular, subscribe

If I call  this.printInvoice() method under subscribe scope it shows error  Cannot read property 'document' of null

```
onSubmit() {
           this.ItemSellService.addItemSale(this.item_sale).subscribe(res => {
               if (res.success) {
                   this.printInvoice();
               } else {
                  // fail message
               }
           })
       }

printInvoice(): void {
               let printContents, popupWin;
               printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
               popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
               popupWin.document.open();
               popupWin.document.write(`
                 <html>
                   <head>
                     <title>Print tab</title>
                     <style>
                     //........Customized style.......
                     </style>
                   </head>
               <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
                 </html>`
               );
               popupWin.document.close();
           }
```

But its working fine form outside of the subscribe scope like:

```
onSubmit() {
     this.printInvoice();
                   this.ItemSellService.addItemSale(this.item_sale).subscribe(res => {
                       if (res.success) {
                           // I need to call after successful operation
                       } else {
                          // fail message
                       }
                   })
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Changed onload="window.printInvoice();window.close()"  instead of onload="window.print();window.close()"

```
printInvoice(): void {
               let printContents, popupWin;
               printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
               popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
               popupWin.document.open();
               popupWin.document.write(`
                 <html>
                   <head>
                     <title>Print tab</title>
                     <style>
                     //........Customized style.......
                     </style>
                   </head>
               <body onload="window.printInvoice();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
                 </html>`
               );
               popupWin.document.close();
           }
```

Comment: For everyone where the accepted answer doesnt work, maybe this is your problem: When its taking too long to call the subscribe (for example a http request takes like 20 seconds) then chrome (And possibly other browsers) block the window.open because its "not invoked by a user interaction" anymore. Only solution i see in this case is to create the window before calling the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onSubmit() {
       var that = this; // use this context where the function works as expected 

       this.ItemSellService.addItemSale(this.item_sale).subscribe(res => {
           if (res.success) {
               that.printInvoice();
           } else {
              // fail message
           }
       })
   }
```

Comment: @saif did you look in the console? Is there an error that stops the execution?